# How to pass check box value one page other page in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am using check box in  input page its have name value S it's looks like

HOME PAGE:

```
  <div class="col-md-1 padding-lft" style="right:13px;top:3px">
    <input id="chkUFtoLoan-2" type="checkbox" name="N" /> 
     </div>
```

This check box value pass Results.php

i  have tired this method its not Working

```
<?php 

session_start();

$checkbox1 = $_POST["S"];
?>
```

i have tired and used Echo and  print_ r its not working ? how to pass one to another page check box value ?

Comment: Well, you named your checkbox `N`, but you're trying to call it as something named `S`.

Answer (score 1):

Change `$checkbox1 = $_POST["S"];` to `$checkbox1 = $_POST["N"];`, as your checkbox name is `N`.

#### Also checkbox value will submit only when its `checked`.

Comment: i am edited but i have tired show value echo function value not showing

Comment: @samyNathanP Please post your `<form>` code also in your question.

Comment: <form action="" id="frmCalculators" method="post"  name="frmCalculator">  its my form enter this my top of the code

Comment: @samyNathanP Above form is missing `action="Results.php"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Where are you Passing Value. ?? You have to pass value to see .
(value="S")    

<div class="col-md-1 padding-lft" style="right:13px;top:3px">
    <input id="chkUFtoLoan-2" type="checkbox" name="S" value="S"/> 
</div>

<?php 

session_start();

echo $checkbox1 = $_POST["S"];
?>
```